# Implementing equations in R

Tags: r, equation-solving

I am new to R (also not too good at math) and I am trying to calculate this equation in R with some difficulties:

[image: The formula I am trying to calculate]

X is some integer data I have, with 550 samples.

Any help is appreciated since I am unsure how to do this. I think I have to use a for loop and the `sum()` function but other than that I don;t know.

Comment: There's no indication about `x` in your picture. It varies from what to what?

Comment: Do you mean the data? It ranges from 5.3 to 45.6.

Answer (score 2):

R supports vectorisation, which means you very rarely need to implement for loops.

For example, you can solve your equation like so:

```r
## I'm just making up a long numerical vector for x - obviously you can use anything
x <- 1:1000
solution <- sum(20/x)^0.5
```

Unless the brackets denote the integral, rather than the sum? In which case:

```r
solution <- sum( (20/x)^0.5 )
```

Comment: I think the brackets `[]` denote the integral part.

Comment: I've seen your edit. The integral *part*, i.e. `floor`.

Comment: Hi sorry, I used the wrong equation. I edited my original post. I don't fully understand what is meant by integral part though.

Comment: @htu.98 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: Oh no, I don't think my equation uses them.